# Specify compression type with Athena

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I have S3 data which is has `GZIP` compression. I'm trying to create a table in Athena using this file, and my `CREATE TABLE` statement succeeds - but when I query the table all rows are empty.

```
create external table mydatabase.table1 (
   date date,
   week_begin_date date,
   week_end_date date,
   value float
)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
stored as inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'     
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3://my-bucket/some/path/'
```

How can I insist that Athena read my files as `GZIP`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While Athena supports `TBLPROPERTIES` metadata (we can set properties within a `CREATE TABLE`, [`ALTER TABLE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-set-tblproperties.html) to set these properties, and [`SHOW TBLPROPERTIES`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-tblproperties.html) to display properties of any table), it *does not* respect the `TBLPROPERTIES ('compressionType'='gzip')` option.

There's no apparent way to force compression / decompression algorithm. Athena attempts to identify compression based on file extension. A `GZIP` file with a `.gz` suffix will be readable; a `GZIP` file without that suffix will not.

Similarly, an uncompressed file with a `.gz` suffix will fail. The reported error is

> HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: incorrect header check

Some investigation revealed the following:

- The only known way to have Athena recognize a file as a `GZIP` is to name it with a `.gz` suffix.
- Other similar suffixes that *do not* work include `.gzip`, `.zip`, `[^.]gz`
- `GZIP` and uncompressed files can live happily side by side in an Athena table or partition - the compression detection is done at the file level, not at the table level.